# How to keep specific area of content view within a visible frame while zooming in scrollview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, pixel

I have cursor inside scroll content view. I am maintaining relative cursor size when zoom in but its going out of frame. I don't want to keep in center but I have to make sure it's always visible.

Before Zoom:

[image: Before zoom]

After Zoom:

[image: After zoom]

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you also don't want the user to be able to scroll the "selected rectangle) out of view...

One approach is to calculate the min and max content offsets in `scrollViewDidScroll` to make sure the "focus rect" is fully visible:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    guard let fv = focusView else { return }
    
    // get min and max scroll offsets
    let mnx = fv.frame.minX * scrollView.zoomScale
    let mny = fv.frame.minY * scrollView.zoomScale
    let mxx = (fv.frame.maxX * scrollView.zoomScale) - scrollView.frame.width
    let mxy = (fv.frame.maxY * scrollView.zoomScale) - scrollView.frame.height
    let newX = max(min(scrollView.contentOffset.x, mnx), mxx)
    let newY = max(min(scrollView.contentOffset.y, mny), mxy)
    
    // update scroll offset if needed
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
    
}
```

Here's a quick example, using 6 subviews. For your "checkerboard grid" you would probably track a "focus rect" instead of a "focus view", but the same principle applies:

```
class RestrictZoomViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let v = UIScrollView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        return v
    }()
    let contentView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        return v
    }()

    var focusView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        [contentView, scrollView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        let safeG = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        let contentG = scrollView.contentLayoutGuide
        let frameG = scrollView.frameLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeG.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentG.bottomAnchor),
            
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.widthAnchor),
            contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: frameG.heightAnchor),

        ])
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed, .systemGreen, .systemBlue,
            .orange, .purple, .brown,
        ]

        colors.forEach { c in
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = c
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler(_:)))
            v.addGestureRecognizer(t)
            contentView.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
        scrollView.bouncesZoom = false
        scrollView.delegate = self
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // only want to do this once
        if let firstView = contentView.subviews.first,
           firstView.frame.width == 0 {
            var x:CGFloat = 40
            let y: CGFloat = 160
            var j = 0
            for _ in 0..<(contentView.subviews.count / 2) {
                contentView.subviews[j].frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 60, height: 60)
                j += 1
                contentView.subviews[j].frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y + 100, width: 60, height: 60)
                j += 1
                x += 100
            }
        }
        
    }

    @objc func tapHandler(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let v = g.view else { return }
        
        if let fv = focusView {
            fv.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }

        // "highlight" tapped view
        v.layer.borderWidth = 1
        // set it as focusView
        focusView = v
        // adjust scroll offset if new focusView is not fully visible
        scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return contentView
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        guard let fv = focusView else { return }
        
        // get min and max scroll offsets
        let mnx = fv.frame.minX * scrollView.zoomScale
        let mny = fv.frame.minY * scrollView.zoomScale
        let mxx = (fv.frame.maxX * scrollView.zoomScale) - scrollView.frame.width
        let mxy = (fv.frame.maxY * scrollView.zoomScale) - scrollView.frame.height
        let newX = max(min(scrollView.contentOffset.x, mnx), mxx)
        let newY = max(min(scrollView.contentOffset.y, mny), mxy)
        
        // update scroll offset if needed
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
        
    }
}
```